# Vuetify Autocomplete Showing [object Object]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am new in vue 3. I am trying to use vuetify autocomplete feature for my project. I have consulted official doc of [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/) . Autocomplete Showing [object Object]. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    import { Form, Field } from 'vee-validate';


    export default {
        components: {
            Form,
            Field,
        },
        setup(props) {
            
        },
        data() {
            return {
                add: {
                    id: 1,
                },
                states: [
                    { name: 'Florida', id: 1 },
                    { name: 'Georgia', id: 2 },
                    { name: 'Nebraska', id: 3 },
                    { name: 'California', id: 4 },
                    { name: 'New York', id: 5 },
                ],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            
            },

        
    };
</script>
<template>
<v-row>
    <v-autocomplete
    v-model="add.id"
    :items="states"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    chips
    deletable-chips
    filled
></v-autocomplete>
</v-row>
</template>
```

How to show state name instead of [object object]

Comment: First of all, what version of Vuetify have you installed? 2.6 is only for Vue 2, you have to follow this guide for Vue 3: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Vuetify 3, you should use "item-title" instead of "item-text".
And i think that Vuetify 2.6 is not compatible with Vue 3.

Give a feedback if this worked for you or not.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you mentioned the wrong reference URL of Vuetify (or maybe you are using the wrong version) because **Vuetify 2** is not compatible with **Vue 3**. So, use [Vuetify 3](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/) for your development.

Second, if you don't want to select multiple items (because you didn't use `multiple` props) then the use of the `chips` prop doesn't seem worth it. However, if you want to use it, fix two syntax mistakes first-

- Use `closable-chips` instead of `deletable-chips` (it is Vuetify 2 syntax.).
- Use `variant="filled"` instead of `filled` (it is also Vuetify 2 syntax.)

**Now, the reason autocomplete is showing `object object` is that you are using `item-text` which is Vuetify 2 belonging. Instead of that, you should use `item-title`  and the issue will be fixed.**

Here is the working demo of output when using `item-text` and when using `item-title`-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
      <v-app>
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-row no-gutters>
              <v-col>
                <h3 class="my-2">When using "item-text"</h3>
                <v-autocomplete
                  v-model="add.id"
                  :items="states"
                  item-text="name"
                  item-value="id"
                  variant="filled"
                  chips
                  closable-chips
                  ></v-autocomplete>
              </v-col>
              <v-col class="ms-3">
                <h3 class="my-2">When using "item-title"</h3>
                <v-autocomplete
                  v-model="add.id"
                  :items="states"
                  item-title="name"
                  item-value="id"
                  variant="filled"
                  chips
                  closable-chips
                  ></v-autocomplete>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-app>
    </script>
    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;
      const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
      
      const vuetify = createVuetify();
      
      const app = createApp({
        template: "#app-template",
        data() {
            return {
                add: {
                    id: 1,
                },
                states: [
                    { name: 'Florida', id: 1 },
                    { name: 'Georgia', id: 2 },
                    { name: 'Nebraska', id: 3 },
                    { name: 'California', id: 4 },
                    { name: 'New York', id: 5 },
                ],
            };
        },
      })
      .use(vuetify)
      .mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `return-object` in v-autocomplete

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="add.id"
    :items="states"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    chips
    deletable-chips
    filled
    return-object
></v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:items="states.map(x=> x.name)"` you need to use a string array.